# Apache virtual host issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony

I am trying to get Symfony to work without using the built in PHP server, however, I always get 403 when trying to access it via my virtual host address.  My virtual host conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.symfony2.local
        ServerAlias symfony2.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/symfony2.local/web

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/symfony2.local/web>
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/symfony2-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/symfony2-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 symfony2.local
```

The **.htaccess** in **web/** is the default Synfony2 installed file.

Whenever I try to access http://synfony2.local I get the following error in my log file:

```
(13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:32858] AH00529: /var/www/vhosts/symfony2.local/web/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/vhosts/symfony2.local/web/' is executable

-rwxr-xr-x. 1 apache apache 2.8K Mar  1 00:48 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x.  3 apache apache 4.0K Mar  1 01:24 web
```

Can someone please point out what I am missing here?

Comment: Make sure that `symfony2.local` is 755 permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by [Panama Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820770/apache-virtual-host-issue/28821034#28821034) was useful and the points raised valid, however, it did not resolve the issue (although it may have had an effect).

I finally managed to get it to work after disabling SeLinux.

Answer (score 2):

There could be serveral reasons for the 403 foribben.

1. **Reduce the permissions** on the .htaccess file. You have the wrong
   permissions on the htaccess file. You have it as **755** which should be used on directories and it should
   be **644 rw-r--r--**. Change it. My guess is that's the problem.
2. Make sure you have an index file in the web root. Of course if you have a web app there then make sure you have the `DirectoryIndex index.php` specified in the Apache config file.
3. Make sure the parent folder is `755` `symfony2.local` also which has been known to restrict access.

Option 2 and 3 are something to check if 1 doesn't fix it. Although you need to change the perms on htaccess regardless.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not appear to have resolved the issue.  I still get the same error message in the log file and when I access the page I get "You don't have permission to access / on this server".